Functional equation $f(x+2024)=\frac{1+f(x)}{1-f(x)}$

Find all continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying the equality$$f(x+2024)=\frac{1+f(x)}{1-f(x)} \forall x\in \mathbb{R}.$$

I have an idea for a solution, but I'm not sure if it's correct
$$f(x)=\frac{1+f(x-2024)}{1-f(x-2024)}$$
then
$$f(x+2024)=\frac{1+\frac{1+f(x-2024)}{1-f(x-2024)}}{1-\frac{1+f(x-2024)}{1-f(x-2024)}}=\frac{-1}{f(x-2024)}$$
So there exists $\exists x_0 \in [x-2024,x+2024]$ such that $f(x_0)=0$, but at the same time $f(x_0+4048)=\frac{-1}{f(x_0)}$.
Let $\lim_{x\to(x_0-0)}f(x+4048)=+\infty$, then $\lim_{x\to(x_0+0)}f(x+4048) =-\infty $.
So the function is not continuous. A contradiction. So there are no such functions.

It looks good. The last step is superfluous because you already know that division-by-zero occurs, rendering $f$ not definable at that point.

Are you sure about the signage of the limit? I believe that depends on the behavior around $f(x_0)$, which you don't have control over. EG They could both tend to positive infinity.

Yes, I’m sure since the function is continuous and will take both positive and negative values on[x-2024,x+2024], then $\exists (x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$ where the function takes positive and negative values

@SangchulLee's comment could be an answer.
